# WSO2 IS 5.0.0 SP01 Access tokens are not expiring at set times?

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I just started using WSO2 IS version 5.0.0 with SP01 installed. I have configured a relying party and I am attempting to use the Open ID Connect/ Oauth 2.0 protocol in order to authenticate my users using a read-only LDAP.

The documentation states that we can control the expiry time of in the  following XML configuration tags found in PRODUCT_HOME/repository/conf/identity.xml

```
<!-- Default validity period for Authorization Code in seconds -->
<AuthorizationCodeDefaultValidityPeriod>300</AuthorizationCodeDefaultValidityPeriod>

<!-- Default validity period for user access tokens in seconds (default: 3600) -->
<AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>60</AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>

<!-- Default validity period for application access tokens in seconds (default: 3600)-->
<UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>60</UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>

<!-- Validity period for refresh token -->
<RefreshTokenValidityPeriod>84600</RefreshTokenValidityPeriod>

<!-- Timestamp skew in seconds -->
<TimestampSkew>300</TimestampSkew>

<!-- Enable OAuth caching -->
<EnableOAuthCache>true</EnableOAuthCache>
```

I have set both the AccessTokenDefaultValidity and the UserAccessTokenValidity to be 60 instead of 3600 but it seems that the WSO2 IS application does not expire them in the time that is set.

Also I am using the PASSWORD grant type to create the Access Token.

To test this I am using a Java client written to contact the server and send the username and password. This works fine as it generates the access Token.

This is the response from the WSO2 IS server (minus the id_token for security): 
{"scope":"openid","token_type":"bearer",**"expires_in":0**,"refresh_token":"a3699846516d7c39c24fea76171bd41", "access_token":"88286cb21f3a9888945eb806f8abcef"}

I think the **expires_in** is wrong because it says 0 seconds, in otherwords my generated tokens should expire immediately. Based on my configuration I would expect it to say 60 seconds.

After waiting approximately 1+ minute, I can still use the access token to get my id_token and therefore the protected claims again, even though it should be expired as per the xml configuration.

Note: I am not using WSO2 IS APIM, this is only for the IS product.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue in Wso2 Identity Server. Hope I am missing something at configuration level. Need help to figure it out.Thanks.